# Django: Customize the User model's return field

Tags: django, django-models

The default return field of Django's User model is 'username'. However, my application needs it to be 'first_name'.
Currently, I just forked Django and made this change to the User model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

It works fine, but I wonder if there are other SIMPLE ways of doing this without forking Django?

Comment: editing library is not a proper solution. You should subclass user model and use the str function within the child class.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a way to inject a new method on your `User` class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_first_name(self):
    return self.first_name

User.add_to_class("__str__", get_first_name)
```

You can put this in a `common` application (preferably inside `models.py`)

Not very clean, but does the job without overriding the entire `User` model, if you only need this single change.

Comment: Dynamically adding methods to an existing class without inheriting it, python literally blows my mind.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to do this would be to use a [custom user model](https://learnbatta.com/blog/using-custom-user-model-in-django-23/), then define `get_full_name()` and/or `get_short_name()` to return `first_name`.

Comment: There are situations when you don't want to add a custom user model in the project. But still, the best way.

Answer (score 3):

First, create a custom user using [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/)

Once, you have your custom user, go to **MyUser** Class. Add fields like first_name, last_name or whatever you need.

You will get some thing like this.

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Now, Edit **__str__** function inside your class to this.

```
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.first_name
```

Remember, fields like date_of_birth etc are optional.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Randy Tang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214320/django-customize-the-user-models-return-field/34418762#34418762): you can avoid [the issue Ramast mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214320/django-customize-the-user-models-return-field#comment56620418_34418762) by using a [Proxy Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models):

```py
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

As per the docs:

> You can create, delete and update instances of the proxy model and all
>   the data will be saved as if you were using the original (non-proxied)
>   model.

Answer (score 0):

Will the following solution work?

```
class MyUser(User):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

And don't use `User` anymore, use `MyUser` instead.

Comment: Sadly that would create another DB table called my_user with same fields as User model. Whatever value you store in MyUser object can not be accessed from User object and vise versa

Comment: Correct.  In order to not use the default User mode anymore, you would have to do:  from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser  and then  class MyUser(AbstractUser).  You would then have access to first_name through MyUser without even having to define it.  You could also inherit from AbstractBaseUser, but that is more complicated to implement.

Comment: You could also define the `db_table` attribute in the `Meta` class as `auth_user`, to force Django to use the same DB table as the contrib user model would.