# Dango admin throws empty exception when calling __str__ method

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm developping a web app with Django (2.2).
I have the following Profile model extending the built-in User model trough an One-to-one relationship.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user__last_name']

    txt = models.CharField("TXT", max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    colleague = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """ Display of User with its full name"""
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.last_name.upper(), self.user.first_name.capitalize())
```

The __str__ method works well in the Admin list display view or in a Django shell.
However, an exception is thrown when I try to access to the admin form, pointing to the __str__ method but without any detail.

When the __str__ method is removed the form is displayed correctly.

Here is the ModelAdmin

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('get_last_name','get_first_name',)

    fieldsets = [
        ('User', 
         {'fields': ['get_last_name', 'get_first_name','txt', 'colleague']}),
    ]
    #Sélection des champs à afficher dans la vue liste
    list_display = ('__str__','get_poste','txt', 'colleague ')

    #Champ de recherche
    search_fields = ['user__first_name',
                     'user__last_name',
                     ]

    #calculate fields for list_display
    def get_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name
    def get_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.first_name

    #Define description of fields for list_display
    get_last_name.short_description = 'Name'
    get_first_name.short_description = 'Firstname'

    #Enable sorting on calculated fields
    get_last_name.admin_order_field = 'user__last_name'
    get_first_name.admin_order_field = 'user__first_name'
```

Any advice to solve this issue would be appreciated

Comment: you mean exception is thrown when you access the add profile form?

Comment: I have disabled the add form. I'm trying to access to the record to modify it. I don't know whether the add and modification form are identicals.

Comment: You don't even see any exception trace on the terminal?

Comment: I get only this :  
Stack trace:  
 >  File "C:\...\app\models.py", line 108, in __str__   
 >    return "%s %s" % (self.user.last_name, self.user.first_name)

And then a list of loaded modules: 'app.models', 'django.db.models.base', 'pprint', 'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.panel', 'django.dispatch.dispatcher', 'django.test.utils', 'django.template.base', 'django.template.backends.django', 'django.template.response'
, 'django.core.handlers.base', 'django.core.handlers.exception', 'debug_toolbar.panels'...

Comment: `"%s %s" % (self.user.last_name, self.user.first_name)` will throw an error if the `profile` is not linked to a user. You could avoid this by using `return "%s %s" % (self.user.last_name, self.user.first_name) if self.user is not None else "No user"`, or you could fix up any profiles with broken users in your database.

Comment: I have already tested the `if` without success and also cheked that none of my Profiles is broken. I have the same exception with all my profiles instances.

Comment: If the `if` doesn't work, then [edit] your question with the new code and full traceback. Without that, we can't tell why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the object does not have a `first_name` and `last_name` yet, thus you are calling `null.upper()` and `null.capitalize()`. Try to handle that inside the `__str__` function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The User object has these 2 attributes and removing upper/capitalize methods does not avoid the exception

Comment: In the terminal, I get only this : `Stack trace: > File "C:\...\app\models.py", line 108, in str > return "%s %s" % (self.user.last_name, self.user.first_name)`

Comment: Actually now that i give a closer look the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display i fear that you cannot really use internal methods. I would try to rename the __str__ to sth else and then call that from __str__ and the form.

Comment: I have also checked the doc. In fact, it's possible to use \_\_str\_\_ in list_display and it works in Profile model. The exception is raised when I try to access to the change form. I have other models with customized \_\_str\_\_ methods that are working correctly but the Profile \_\_str\_\_ method is the only one that returns foreignkey attributes

Comment: have you tried setting a pdb on the `__str__` method to see if it calls the right `__str__`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around the problem by adding a field name to the profile model, updating it automatically trough a custom .save() method and returning it with __str__ :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user__last_name']

    txt = models.CharField("TXT", max_length=5, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    colleague = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = self.user.__str__()
        return super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        """ Display of User with its full name"""
        return self.name
```

I also customized User str method according to [Django: Customize the User model's return field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214320/django-customize-the-user-models-return-field)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_fullname(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.last_name.upper(), self.first_name.capitalize())

User.add_to_class("__str__", get_fullname)
```

Thanks for taking the time to respond